# What are some examples / case studies of apps that did better due to improved UX?

Tags: mobile, case-studies

Are there any good examples / case studies of mobile applications revamped (improved UX) that have a higher conversion due to the UX adjustments?

Comment: Hi Catandmouse. There are lots of examples out there. Unfortunately UX.SE isn't a good medium to point to such things. "lists of [something]" are  generally off-topic here, since there is no "correct" answer to a bunch of lists that are all equally valuable.

Comment: This is a great shame. This is one of the few questions that could have demonstrated data as a strong point, in more ways than one. All the "show me data or I don't believe..." questions are usually pointless. This one is not.

Answer (score 2):

Most studies on this seem to come down to navigation, as that is usually the biggest difference between mobile and desktop variants.

Conversion for mobile often boils down to how you present certain choices in the  login and check-out/shopping cart steps. Asking for private data or app rights (such as facebook etc) in the wrong way can scare people off, killing conversion.

Not exactly what you asked for, but I did find 2 helpfull navigation case studies:

[Case-study on the effect of the hamburger menu](https://redbooth.com/blog/hamburger-menu-iphone-app)

[Case-study on the impact of side drawers navigation on mobile](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2014/04/08/ux-designers-side-drawer-navigation-costing-half-user-engagement/#gref)